# Problem 14 chapter 5 from PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be differentiable real function defined in $(a,b)$. Prove that $f$ is convex **iff** $f'$ is monotonically increasing. Assume next that $f''(x)$ exists for every $x\in (a,b)$, and prove that $f$ is convex **iff** $f''(x)\geqslant 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

**Proof:** $\Rightarrow$ Let $f$ is convex in $(a,b)$ then for any $a<s<t<h<u<b$  we have $$\dfrac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\leqslant\dfrac{f(h)-f(s)}{h-s}\leqslant\dfrac{f(h)-f(t)}{h-t}\leqslant\dfrac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}\leqslant\dfrac{f(u)-f(h)}{u-h}.$$ Considering the first and last terms of inequality and letting $t\to s+$ we have: $f'_{+}(s)\leqslant \frac{f(u)-f(h)}{u-h}$ and letting $h\to u-$ we have $f'_{+}(s)\leqslant f'_{-}(u)$. Since $f'$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ then $f'(s)\leqslant f'(u)$.

$\Leftarrow$ Let $f'$ is increasing in $(a,b)$. Let $s,u$ any numbers from $(a,b)$ such that $s<u$. Taking any $t\in (s,u)$ then $f(t)-f(s)=(t-s)f'(\theta_1)$ and $f(u)-f(t)=(u-t)f'(\theta_2)$ for some $\theta_1\in (s,t)$ and $\theta_2\in (t,u)$. But $f'(\theta_1)\leqslant f'(\theta_2)$ then $$\dfrac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\leqslant\dfrac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}.$$ Then $f(t)\leqslant \lambda_1f(s)+\lambda_2f(u),$ where $\lambda_1=\dfrac{u-t}{u-s}$, $\lambda_2=\dfrac{t-s}{u-s}$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$.

Q.E.D.

The second part is obvious.

Is above proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.